# Is there a way to extend the training set initially passed to a SVC?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I want to simulate Active Learning in Python. I have an initial training set and a pool of unlabeled potential training data. Now, I want to choose iteratively one single element of my pool, add it to the training set passed to the SVC, and retrain the SVC with the new set.
I am unsure how to do it properly. I could either do (Pseudo-Code):

```
for i in range(100):
    linearSVC = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
    linearSVC.fit(X_train, y_train)
    addElementToXtrainSetAndYtrainSet()
```

Or:

```
linearSVC = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
for i in range(100):
    linearSVC.fit(X_train, y_train)
    addElementToXtrainSetAndYtrainSet()
```

The first would definitely work for me. Every iteration a new SVC is trained with iteratively enlarged training data. But it feels wrong to reinitialize the SVC over and over again.
Regarding the second approach, I am unsure if the SVC retrains from scratch or keeps its state from previous iterations and retrains on top of this state. I do not want that. If this is the case, I thought that there might be an option to add subsequently one element to the old state without passing the entire training data again.
But neither do I know how `.fit` behaves behind the curtain, nor could I find such an option. Is there a "good" way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to accomplish is basically the principle of Stochastic Gradient Descent. As such, I propose to use the [`SGDClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html?highlight=sgdclassifier#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.fit) of `scikit-learn`. From its documentation:

> This estimator implements regularized linear models with stochastic gradient descent (SGD) learning: **the gradient of the loss is estimated each sample at a time and the model is updated along the way** with a decreasing strength schedule (aka learning rate). SGD allows minibatch (online/out-of-core) learning via the ***partial_fit*** method.

Depending on the specified loss function, it will fit a different model. It defaults to ***hinge* loss** which is **equivalent to a linear SVM**.

In your case, you would train a `SGDClassifier` with a hinge loss on your initial training data with the `fit()` function, and then update the model with elements of your potential training data with `partial_fit()` one at a time:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier


linearSVC = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge') # hinge is default loss anyway, just shown for clarity

# Fit on initial training set
linearSVC.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Update model one sample at a time
for i in range(100):
    linearSVC.partial_fit(X_pool[i], y_pool[i])
```

This will work as desired. As a reference, you can also see the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052342/what-is-the-difference-between-partial-fit-and-warm-start) where it is clarified that

> *[...] when fitting new data to your model, partial_fit will only correct the model one step towards the new data [...]*

A final note though since you passed the `probability=True` parameter in your example. Be aware that this classifier only supports the `predict_proba()` function for log loss and modified Huber loss. As a consequence, you might not be able to predict the probabilities for your classes.

Comment: is there any possibility to add or simulate the functionality of `predict_proba()`? Unluckily it is essential for choosing the "correct" instance from the pool at each iteration :/

Comment: @Lavair Given that you definitely want to stay with the SVM as a model, there is no straightforward way to do so, at least afaik. If having an SVM as an underlying model is not that important, you could of course try the `log` loss which results in a LogisticRegression model, and then the `SGDClassifier` will support `predict_proba()`. Otherwise, I am afraid I can't help you further, at least for now. But it might be worth asking this as a separate question. I believe it would maximize your chances to get a definite answer.